# Dynamically loading erlang header files

Tags: erlang

I know that you can dynamically load erlang beam files in an erlang node using "l(module_name).". My question is is it possible to load ".hrl" files the same way or some such similar without having to restart an erlang node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this is possible, but just based on understanding, when you try to define an macro in url and you want to modify it, the compiler replaces the macro during the compilation of the erlang file by replacing the the macros that are defined in header.

Logically you should rebuilding you code and deploy it again. I don't understand a reason why you need hrl files to be loaded dynamically if you have an option for replacing the entire code dynamically. IMHO all you need to do is rebuild and upgrade and this also can be done without restarting erlang node.

Comment: Ok i get it now, so instead of trying to load the .hrl file directly I should instead recompile the erlang files after modifying the .hrl and load the updated beams. Since you were specifically talking about macros, can I also assume that this applies to "records" defined in .hrl files as well?

Comment: Header files, as with all compiled languages (correct me if I'm wrong), are included at compilation time, so building new BEAMs should be sufficient. And yes, that does apply to records as well. Be wary that if you modify record definitions in a header file, you must reload all modules that include that header file (and use the record), lest you drown yourself in badmatch errors.

Answer (score 0):

".hrl" files - used only by compiler on compile sources. It is not is runtime files.

You can use popular auto-reloader by Mochi team 
https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/blob/master/src/reloader.erl

put them in your src/ folder and add to your exec erl   `-s reloader` option

Comment: ah thanks, the whole thing makes a lot more sense now, i kept thinking .hrl files were needed at runtime as well. 

still a newb at erlang